# Ingress and gRPC multiple paths not working

Tags: .net, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am facing problem when using multiple paths using Ingress with gRPC.

If my Ingress is configured as below, it works fine:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: txc-dev-ingress-grpc
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPC"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: api-dev.txc.mydomain.net
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: tenant-api-svc
            port:
              number: 9000
  tls:
  - secretName: grpctls
    hosts:
      - api-dev.txc.mydomain.net
```

But once I start to plan to use multiple paths like below, it doesn't work anymore:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: txc-dev-ingress-grpc
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPC"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: api-dev.txc.mydomain.net
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /tenantgrpctest(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: tenant-api-svc
            port:
              number: 9000
  tls:
  - secretName: grpctls
    hosts:
      - api-dev.txc.mydomain.net
```

Maybe my Ingress configuration is wrong?

Below is my C# code:

```
using Grpc.Net.Client;

using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://api-dev.txc.mydomain.net/tenantgrpctest");
var client = new TXC.Proto.Tenant.TenantConfig.TenantConfigClient(channel);
var reply = client.GetTenantConfig(new TXC.Proto.Tenant.GetTenantConfigRequest() { TenantId = 2});

// Check the message
Console.WriteLine("Test: " + reply.Message);
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

The error I receive is 404 Not Found.

Comment: Please make sure when using the NGINX-Ingress controller that the version is >0.30.0 when trying to use gRPC. Additionally please read about Ingress matching and regexp: [Ingress path matching](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/)

Comment: Thanks Srividya. I realize the issue is because of the special path that grpc creates. This link helped me: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-6.0